# Force User Login

Tags: redirect, login

Surprised I haven't found this Q.

I want to force users to login to the site before accessing any of the content.

I have this function:

```
function av_force_user_login() {
    global $post;
    global $pagenow;
    if ( in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) ) ) {
        return;
    }else{
        auth_redirect();
    }
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'av_force_user_login' );
```

This doesn't seem to work though and after I try and login I get redirected back to the login page.

One caveats to watch out for (in my case): I'm using BuddyPress' registration system which doesn't apply to the login page but it would apply to the `wp-login.php?action=register` page which redirects to Buddypress' template for registration.

Nevertheless, is there anything wrong with the above code that would cause a redirect back to the login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Basic Script. This should work.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_login');

function redirect_to_login(){
 if(!is_user_logged_in()){
   // user not logged in so redirect them to login page
   $redirect_url = '' // you can determine where to redirect user after they login
   wp_redirect( wp_login_url($redirect_url), 301 ); exit;
 }
}
```